# Creating a database within bash script in a virtual machine

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, sh

I want to create a mysql database under my virtual machine using a bash script.
I created a bash script that contains commands to create a mysql schema and to run a .sql script, here bellow some of the content of the bash script :

```
CONFIGDB=$WORKSPACEPATH/dbaccess.cnf
DATABASE=dbTest
mysql --defaults-extra-file=$CONFIGDB  "DROP DATABASE $DATABASE;"
mysql --defaults-extra-file=$CONFIGDB  "CREATE SCHEMA $DATABASE DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1;"
mysql --defaults-extra-file=$CONFIGDB --database=$DATABASE < all_files.sql
```

$CONFIGDB is a .cnf file that contains information about the user and his password :

```
[client]
user=server
password="password"
```

I am running those scripts on a virtual machine.
I'm registrating the bash log in a .txt file. When I open the txt file containing the log, there is no indication that the scripts are runned or not.
I went under my virtual machine and I executed the following command :

```
mysql show schemas;
```

My schema dbTest does not appear under the list.

Any suggestion please? it has been days and I can't find a solution

Comment: In your script, add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line.  Then run your script like this: `./thescript.bash >out.txt 2>err.txt`.  And review these files.  If that is not enough, add `-x` to the first line mentionned above.  Also check your DB logs.  You do not indicate anything in your question that we can help with.  Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Debugging

Comment: @Nic3500 thanks you for your answer.. Actually my bash script starts with #!/bin/bash of course and I mentioned that I putted a txt containing the log of my bash script (>log.txt), what are other information that can be helpful?

Comment: Have you tried `2>err.log` to see the error entries (if any) ?

Comment: @Nic3500 yes , in the log no error is displayed, I executed the same bash script locally and it works perfectly, the schema is created and the scripts are runned. The problem is that when I execute the script in the virtual Machine. Neither error or success message is displayed in the .log file.